# why guava cache can only store non-null value in local cache and how to bypass this

Tags: java, caching, guava, ehcache

i'm adding local cache to my server by using google's guava utils.

guava is very suitable for my scenario, except it can only store "non-null" values into its local cache (both com.google.common.cache.Cache and com.google.common.cache.LoadingCache did).

well, this is not good. because my server may fail to get values from remote database, because of time run out or other reasons. if i give a default value to guava, it will be stored in local cache, and will always be there, unless some eviction conditions were met. but the question is i cannot give a reasonable default value to guava.

can somebody tell me, why guava has this constraint, and how can i bypass it? can ehcache be more suited for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want to cache `null` (or anything representing "absent") if you just time out trying to get the value from the remote database? You could throw an exception instead, which will indicate that there was a failure getting the value (as opposed to the value just not existing) and also not add anything to the cache, so that when you try to get the value for the key again it will try to read from the database again.

Comment: yes, null object is not what i need, because they will also be stored into local cache as "default value" does, which is not what i want.

Comment: my problem has been solved by throwing a dummy exception. though i don't think its eligent enough.

Answer (score 9):

Guava is not really null friendly. I invite you to read their manifesto about null [1].

If you have to bypass that behavior, work with `Optional<V>`[2]. So instead of working with `LoadingCache<K, V>` and `CacheLoader<K, V>`, use `LoadingCache<K, Optional<V>>` and `CacheLoader<Optional<V>>`.

This way you keep using the power of `Cache` and add the flexibility `Optional` offers.

1. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained
2. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html

Comment: And of course, as ColinD says, when you have to throw an exception, throw it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Null Object design pattern  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern

Comment: humm... i guess null object is not what i need. but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

In ehcache, you can distinguish null value and non-exist key, but you need an extra `Element` class.

```
// ehcache
cache.put(new Element("key1", null));
assertNull(cache.get("key1").getObjectValue());  // null value
assertNull(cache.get("key2"));  // key is not exist
```

In guava, you don't have to use an extra class, but cannot distinguish null value and non-exist key.

```
// plain guava
cache.put("key1", "value1");
assertNull(cache.getIfPresent("key2"));  // key is not exist
```

As others said, you can use null object pattern or `Optional` with guava. With such an extra class, you can handle `null` value like ehcache.

```
// guava with Optional
cache.put("key1", Optional.absent());
assertFalse(cache.getIfPresent("key1").isPresent());  // null value
assertNull(cache.getIfPresent("key2"));  // key is not exist
```